# Binary to ascii mapping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

This morning I've seen this on Twitter: 
http://mynewtechworld.tumblr.com/post/135545896048

I case that somebody can't see the image:

> I
>   01101100
>   01101111
>   01110110
>   01100101
>   you.

Just for fun I wrote this binary to ascii-converter in JavaScript:

```
var chars = [
  'I ',
  0b01101100,
  0b01101111,
  0b01110110,
  0b01100101,
  ' you.'
];

var result = chars.reduce(function(previous, current) {

  if (!isNaN(current)) {
    current = String.fromCharCode(current.toString());
  }

  return previous + current;
}, '');
```

[My complete implementation on CodePen](http://codepen.io/mizech/pen/KVzjbo)

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, a fine first question :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest splitting:

- Converting binary to ascii
- Concatenating

After defining `binaryToNumber` and `add`. the final code will look much simpler:

```
var result = chars.map(binaryToNumber).reduce(add)
```